# How to boot back into Linux after Windows 10 install

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, boot, bootloader

#### Preface

On this computer I had Windows 7 installed. I accidentally broke it, so I installed Linux Mint (since Linux is free and I didn't want to pay for Windows). Recently I was able to install Windows 10 on the partition that previously contained my broken Windows 7 (I looked at all the files and decided that I had them (or equivalent) stored in other places).

#### Problem

Now this is where my problem comes in. Once I installed Windows 10, it boots up fine... the only problem is that the installation seems to have broken (possibly overwritten) the GRUB2 bootloader, and now I can't boot into Linux.

**I've looked at many Q&As here on Super User, but none of them worked**.
(*so please don't mark this as a duplicate unless I say it works in my situation! Thank you*)

#### Possible Solution #1

There was one that got *pretty* close to solving my problem. It was having me use EasyBCD to add Linux to the bootloader, but I didn't know where the boot files are stored in a Linux system.
I don't know how others are, but I have three partitions, one for the filesystem (which this is where I suspected the boot files to be, but it didn't work), one for /home (I was going to select this one next, but I wanted to ask this question, before I messed anything up anymore...), and one for the swap (I know the boot files aren't in this partition).

#### Possible Solution #2

One was talking about installing Linux and then using some BCD software to add it to the bootloader, would this work in my situation? When Linux is *already* installed?

#### Final thoughts

For anyone who answers my question just know that I don't care if I have the GRUB2 bootloader or a Windows bootloader (or one that looks like a Windows bootloader). I just want to be able to boot into both Linux and Windows when I want (since I've found that there are big pros to both)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Regarding your Possible Solution #1
```

I discourage the use Of EasyBCD.To keep it sort - it messes with bootloaders in unpredictable ways and hard to remove completely once installed

[Rod-Smith](https://askubuntu.com/users/93977/rod-smith) on EasyBCD {Taken from [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/334288) answer}

> First, the last I heard, EasyBCD was useless for managing a
> Windows/Linux dual-boot on an EFI-based computer, so I recommend you
> stop trying to use it.

---

```
Regarding Possible Solution #2
```

If you mean like this [use windows bootloader to boot linux](https://superuser.com/a/1606111/777184) (*this is one of my previous answers*)

If this is what you mean then no, this method will not work because linux already installed.

---

**Possible solutions #1**

1.Create a live USB from the ISO of whichever Linux you have

2.Boot the live system

3.Chroot the installed system and reinstall bootloader

> 3A.Mount your partition
>
> ```
> sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt  #Replace sda2 with root partition
> ```
>
> If you have a separate /boot, /var or /usr partitions
>
> ```
> sudo mount /dev/sdXW /mnt/boot
>
> sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt/var
>
> sudo mount /dev/sdXZ /mnt/usr
> ```
>
> 3B.Bind mount some necessary stuff
>
> ```
> for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt$i"; done
> ```
>
> 3C.If Ubuntu is installed in EFI mode
>
> ```
> sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt/boot/efi
> ```
>
> 3D.chroot into your Ubuntu install
>
> ```
> sudo chroot /mnt
> ```
>
> 3E.reinstall grub
>
> ```
> grub-install /dev/sdx
> ```
>
> 3F.Update grub : Regenerate grub files by running `update-grub`
>
> ```
> update-grub
> ```
>
> 3G.If everything worked without errors, then you're all set
>
> ```
> exit
> sudo reboot
> ```

Upon reboot Grub will help you boot desired OS

Comment: Should I just uninstall EasyBCD then? Or is there a better way to remove it?
I haven't checked any of the answers to see if they fix my problem, but I will tomorrow.

Comment: @JacobHornbeck better is to uninstall; do it the usual way - from control panel

Comment: What does it mean by /dev/sdXY?

Comment: @JacobHornbeck {in context to above answer} /dev/sdXY is the ubuntu efi partition; {in general} X is the drive letter  and Y is it's partition number

Answer (score 3):

The free
[Super Grub2 Disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/)
should be able to fix the problem with one click:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Tomorrow I will test it out to see if it fixes my problem!